# Unable to get a reference for quick settings tile

Tags: java, android

I can set the state of the qs tile using the onClick() method but I would also like to toggle its state using a switch in my Main Activity. However, I can't change the state of the tile using a switch because getQsTile returns null outside the onClick() method.

```
public class AwesomeTileService extends TileService{

Tile tile;
public Activity activity;

public AwesomeTileService(Activity activity){
    this.activity=activity;
    Switch switch1 = (Switch)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            tile=getQsTile(); //tile is null

            SwitchState(); //SwitchState does not work with onCheckedChanged
            Log.v("Switch State=", ""+isChecked);
        }

    });
}

public AwesomeTileService(){
    //zero arg constructor
}


@Override
public void onTileAdded() {
    tile=getQsTile();


    tile.setState(Tile.STATE_INACTIVE);
    tile.updateTile();
}

@Override
public void onClick() {

    tile=getQsTile(); //tile is not null
    SwitchState(); //SwitchState method works with onClick
}

public void SwitchState(){

    if(tile!=null){
        if (tile.getState() == Tile.STATE_INACTIVE) {
            tile.setState(Tile.STATE_ACTIVE);
        }
        else{
            tile.setState(Tile.STATE_INACTIVE);
        }
        tile.updateTile();

    }
}
```

}

I can simply remove the switch from the app but I'm curious to know what the issue is here and how I can overcome it.

Comment: Please post your code as part of question instead of image.

Comment: code in those link

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the tile programmatically from another activity, use sharedPreferences and store boolean value and write code in onStartListening method in tile service class to update tile. (onStartListening is called every time you swipe down the panel).